# Smooth CSS3 transitions issues with Firefox 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

Okay my initial problem was to move an element from left to right. My framework of choice, is jQuery so I used animate.

Here is a simple example. http://jsfiddle.net/7NYwY/3/

In firefox, there is about 3 "pauses" at the same place during the animation. In Chrome these don't appear.

So I thought I'd strip it back further and use CSS3 transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/y6yW6/4/

And I'm getting the exact same "pauses" in the same place. I am presuming that jQuery is abstracting these transitions away from me so its the same code in reality.

So the question is, how would I get this rather simple animation to work smoothly in firefox and chrome.

jQuery would be nice, pure JS if you want to show off.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing CSS3 transitions. This will work smoothly in Chrome / iOS / Android:

```
var ele = $('#bike');

var dx = -500; // transformation
var duration = 3000; // duration in ms.
ele.css({ 
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + -dx + 'px,0px,0px)', 
            '-webkit-transition-duration': (duration || 0) + 'ms', 
            '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden', 
            '-webkit-transition-property': '-webkit-transform' 
});
```

More or less the same for Firefox, but you can easily fiddle that out.

Comment: Hmm seeing the exact same pausing in firefox using the above example fiddled for moz. http://jsfiddle.net/mj8YU/2/ I don't have an issue with chrome using jQuery animate or the other CSS example. Not only my machine it seems either, lots of machines (linux, windows and mac) have the same issue with the pauses. :(

Comment: Couldn't this be a problem with JsFiddle? I use the same technique live and it works smooth as hell. Can you put it in a seperate HTML file?

Comment: Its the same on a plain old html file on my local machine. However I've upgraded to FF7 and it isn't as bad. I'll just have to work with jQuery animate as I need to do things on each step too. Hope for the best...